# Existence of smooth vector field.

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, vector-fields

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth domain in $\mathbb R^n$ and let $x\in\partial\Omega$. Let $n(x):\partial\Omega\to\mathbb S^{n-1}$ be the normal vector field. Then there exist a vector field $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega,\mathbb R^n)$ such that $\phi(x)|_{\partial\Omega}=n(x)$ and $|\phi(x)|\leq 1$

How to prove this? In particular, if $\Omega$ is a ball then what is the explicit expressions of such $\phi$? I couldn't do this.

Comment: $\phi \in C^\infty (\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\Omega$ is relatively compact ?

Comment: If $\Omega$ is not relatively compact, there is no chance that $\phi$ is compactly supported.  If $\Omega$ is relatively compact, just use a tubular neighbourhood of $\partial\Omega$ and a smooth cut-off function to construct $\phi$.

Comment: @user10354138 how to use tubular neighborhood of $\partial\Omega$ and smooth cut off? can you tell more or give some references?

Comment: Let's assume $\Omega$ is relatively compact.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\Omega$ is relatively compact, so $\partial\Omega=M$ is a smooth compact hypersurface of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

By the [Tubular Neighbourhood Theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tubular+neighborhood+theorem), and the fact $M$ is closed, the exponential map defines a diffeomorphism $B_\varepsilon(\nu_M\cong M\times\mathbb{R})\to V$, where $\nu_M$ is the normal bundle of $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $V$ is a neighbourhood of $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Thus we can define $\phi\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
\phi(x)=
\begin{cases}
\eta(d(x,M))\cdot n(\operatorname{proj}_M(x)) & x\in V\\
0 & x\notin V
\end{cases}
$$
where $\operatorname{proj}_M\colon V\to M$ is the closest point projection to $M$, $\eta\colon\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ is a bump function that is $1$ on $B_{\varepsilon/3}(0)$ and $0$ outside $B_{2\varepsilon/3}(0)$.  You can check that this $\phi$ (restricted to $\bar\Omega$) satisfies all the desired conditions.

For $\Omega$ the unit ball, it is easy to describe what happens.  We pick the unit radial vector $x/\lvert x\rvert$, multiply it by $\xi(\lvert x\rvert^2)$ where $\xi$ smoothly interpolates say between $0$ on $[0,\frac13]$ and $1$ on $[\frac23,1]$.  If this is not explicit enough for your taste, we can have a very explicit
$$
\phi(x)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x}{\lvert x\rvert}\cdot \exp\left(1-\dfrac1{\lvert x\rvert^2}\right) & x\neq 0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}
$$

---

A counterexample when $\Omega$ is not relatively compact (actually $\partial\Omega$ is not compact is what is needed): Consider $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be the region $xy<1$.  Then $\partial\Omega=\{xy=1\}$ is not compact (since it is not bounded), so there are no compactly supported function on $\overline{\Omega}$ that restricts to a unit vector field on $\partial\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you. But, how to define the exponential map and how its help to define $\phi$? Actually, I don't have much knowledge about the manifold.

Comment: So its enough to take $\partial\Omega$ is bounded instead of taking the set $\Omega$ is relatively compact.

Comment: For $\mathbb{R}^n$, the exponential map is just $\exp_p(v)=p+v$.

Comment: Sorry, yes, $\partial\Omega$ is bounded is enough.

Comment: How can ensure that $\phi$ is smooth because distance function $d(x,M)$ may not smooth enough right?

Comment: $d(x,M)$ is smooth on $V-M$.